# Querying only dimension in a cube using MDX

Tags: mdx, mondrian, saiku

I have a cube with one fact table and four dimensions (Date, Product, Shop and Country). Dimensions are connected to  fact using primary-foreign keys as usual.

I want to query this model for getting only dimensional information (i.e I don't need any fact table columns). For example, I want to see the status (ACTIVE/INACTIVE etc) all shops in all countries.

The query I have written is

```
WITH
MEMBER [Dim shop.Shop id].[Shop count] AS
    Count([Dim shop.Shop id].Members, EXCLUDEEMPTY) --select the count of shop members

SET [~ROWS_Dim country.Country name] AS
    {[Dim country.Country name].[Country name].Members} --All countries

SET [~ROWS_Dim shop.Status] AS
    {[Dim shop.Status].[Status].Members} --All shop statuses
SELECT
NON EMPTY [Dim shop.Shop id].[Shop count] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY NonEmptyCrossJoin([~ROWS_Dim country.Country name], [~ROWS_Dim shop.Status]) ON ROWS
FROM [cube]
WHERE ({[Dim shop.Date to].[2199-12-31 22:59:59.999],[Dim shop.Date to].[2199-12-31 23:59:59.999]}) --Slicing to get only currently inventoried shops
```

The schema looks like below

```
<Schema name="cube">
  <Dimension name="Dim country">
    <Hierarchy name="Cid" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Cid" uniqueMembers="false" column="cid" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Country code name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Country code name" uniqueMembers="false" column="country_code_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Country currency" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Country currency" uniqueMembers="false" column="country_currency" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Country ga id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Country ga id" uniqueMembers="false" column="country_ga_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Country name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Country name" uniqueMembers="false" column="country_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date from" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date from" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_from">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date to" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date to" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_to">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Version" hasAll="true" primaryKey="cid">
      <Table name="dim_country" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Version" uniqueMembers="false" column="version" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Dimension name="Dim date">
    <Hierarchy name="Calendar month" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Calendar month" uniqueMembers="false" column="calendar_month" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Calendar month name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Calendar month name" uniqueMembers="false" column="calendar_month_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Calendar week" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Calendar week" uniqueMembers="false" column="calendar_week" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Calendar year" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Calendar year" uniqueMembers="false" column="calendar_year" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date" uniqueMembers="false" column="date">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date key" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date key" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_key" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Day of month" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Day of month" uniqueMembers="false" column="day_of_month" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Day of week" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Day of week" uniqueMembers="false" column="day_of_week" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Day of week name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Day of week name" uniqueMembers="false" column="day_of_week_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Day of year" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Day of year" uniqueMembers="false" column="day_of_year" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Quarter" hasAll="true" primaryKey="date_key">
      <Table name="dim_date" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Quarter" uniqueMembers="false" column="quarter" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Dimension name="Dim product">
    <Hierarchy name="Brand" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Brand" uniqueMembers="false" column="brand" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Category id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Category id" uniqueMembers="false" column="category_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Category name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Category name" uniqueMembers="false" column="category_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Code" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Code" uniqueMembers="false" column="code" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Created" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Created" uniqueMembers="false" column="created">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Created by" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Created by" uniqueMembers="false" column="created_by" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date from" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date from" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_from">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date to" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date to" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_to">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Ean" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Ean" uniqueMembers="false" column="ean" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Image location high" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Image location high" uniqueMembers="false" column="image_location_high" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Image location low" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Image location low" uniqueMembers="false" column="image_location_low" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Image location thumb" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Image location thumb" uniqueMembers="false" column="image_location_thumb" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Last modified by price" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Last modified by price" uniqueMembers="false" column="last_modified_by_price" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Last modifiedby product" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Last modifiedby product" uniqueMembers="false" column="last_modifiedby_product" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Level0 parent category id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Level0 parent category id" uniqueMembers="false" column="level0_parent_category_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Level0 parent category name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Level0 parent category name" uniqueMembers="false" column="level0_parent_category_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Level1 parent category id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Level1 parent category id" uniqueMembers="false" column="level1_parent_category_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Level1 parent category name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Level1 parent category name" uniqueMembers="false" column="level1_parent_category_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Manufacturer id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Manufacturer id" uniqueMembers="false" column="manufacturer_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Modified product" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Modified product" uniqueMembers="false" column="modified_product">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Price" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Price" uniqueMembers="false" column="price" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Price with shipping" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Price with shipping" uniqueMembers="false" column="price_with_shipping" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Product currency code" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Product currency code" uniqueMembers="false" column="product_currency_code" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Product id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Product id" uniqueMembers="false" column="product_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Product info id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Product info id" uniqueMembers="false" column="product_info_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Product name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Product name" uniqueMembers="false" column="product_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Product page type" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Product page type" uniqueMembers="false" column="product_page_type" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Product pk" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Product pk" uniqueMembers="false" column="product_pk" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Quality" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Quality" uniqueMembers="false" column="quality" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shop active" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shop active" uniqueMembers="false" column="shop_active" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shop id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shop id" uniqueMembers="false" column="shop_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shop paying" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shop paying" uniqueMembers="false" column="shop_paying" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Status product" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Status product" uniqueMembers="false" column="status_product" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Tstamp" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Tstamp" uniqueMembers="false" column="tstamp">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Version" hasAll="true" primaryKey="product_pk">
      <Table name="dim_product" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Version" uniqueMembers="false" column="version" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Dimension name="Dim shop">
    <Hierarchy name="Ac id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Ac id" uniqueMembers="false" column="ac_id" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Ac type" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Ac type" uniqueMembers="false" column="ac_type" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Account status" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Account status" uniqueMembers="false" column="account_status" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Afl network" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Afl network" uniqueMembers="false" column="afl_network" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Afl param" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Afl param" uniqueMembers="false" column="afl_param" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Capping" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Capping" uniqueMembers="false" column="capping" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Co id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Co id" uniqueMembers="false" column="co_id" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Co name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Co name" uniqueMembers="false" column="co_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Co type" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Co type" uniqueMembers="false" column="co_type" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Contract number" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Contract number" uniqueMembers="false" column="contract_number" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Contract type" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Contract type" uniqueMembers="false" column="contract_type" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Country code" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Country code" uniqueMembers="false" column="country_code" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Cpc" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Cpc" uniqueMembers="false" column="cpc" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Cpc earning" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Cpc earning" uniqueMembers="false" column="cpc_earning" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Cpo" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Cpo" uniqueMembers="false" column="cpo" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Created" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Created" uniqueMembers="false" column="created">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Currency" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Currency" uniqueMembers="false" column="currency" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date from" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date from" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_from">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Date to" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Date to" uniqueMembers="false" column="date_to">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Description" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Description" uniqueMembers="false" column="description" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Image location high" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Image location high" uniqueMembers="false" column="image_location_high" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Image location low" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Image location low" uniqueMembers="false" column="image_location_low" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Image location thumb" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Image location thumb" uniqueMembers="false" column="image_location_thumb" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Last modifiedby" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Last modifiedby" uniqueMembers="false" column="last_modifiedby" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Modified" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Modified" uniqueMembers="false" column="modified">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="No deep links" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="No deep links" uniqueMembers="false" column="no_deep_links" type="Boolean">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Opening hours" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Opening hours" uniqueMembers="false" column="opening_hours" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Pay status" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Pay status" uniqueMembers="false" column="pay_status" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Score" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Score" uniqueMembers="false" column="score" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shipping details" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shipping details" uniqueMembers="false" column="shipping_details" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shipping fee" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shipping fee" uniqueMembers="false" column="shipping_fee" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shop id" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shop id" uniqueMembers="false" column="shop_id" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shop name" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shop name" uniqueMembers="false" column="shop_name" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Shop pk" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Shop pk" uniqueMembers="false" column="shop_pk" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Start date" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Start date" uniqueMembers="false" column="start_date">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Status" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Status" uniqueMembers="false" column="status" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Target country" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Target country" uniqueMembers="false" column="target_country" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Type" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Type" uniqueMembers="false" column="type" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Url" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Url" uniqueMembers="false" column="url" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Url policy" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Url policy" uniqueMembers="false" column="url_policy" type="String">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
    <Hierarchy name="Version" hasAll="true" primaryKey="shop_pk">
      <Table name="dim_shop" schema="dw_pp"/>
      <Level name="Version" uniqueMembers="false" column="version" type="Numeric">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Cube name="cube">
    <Table name="fc_analytics" schema="dw_pp"/>
    <DimensionUsage name="Dim country" source="Dim country" foreignKey="country_fk"/>
    <DimensionUsage name="Dim date" source="Dim date" foreignKey="date_fk"/>
    <DimensionUsage name="Dim product" source="Dim product" foreignKey="product_fk"/>
    <DimensionUsage name="Dim shop" source="Dim shop" foreignKey="shop_fk"/>
    <Measure name="Country fk" column="country_fk" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Date fk" column="date_fk" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Product fk" column="product_fk" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Ser id" column="ser_id" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Shop fk" column="shop_fk" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Measure1" column="M1" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Measure2" column="M2" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
    <Measure name="Measure3" column="M3" aggregator="sum" formatString="&#x23;"/>
  </Cube>
</Schema>**strong text**
```

The query runs. But the values are incorrect. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: why is it wrong? Does the script error with an error message? Or does it run but gives you the wrong numbers? If it gives you the wrong numbers then what is wrong with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my fact table. Apparently NonEmptyCrossJoin() does a scan of the fact table first and excludes dimension entries without a fact table entry (which is not what I want. I want to query the dimension independently)

[This](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2006/10/09/mdx-nonempty-exists-and-evil-nonemptycrossjoin.aspx) explains the perils of using NonEmptyCrossJoin()

I used FILTER(CROSSJOIN(,) AS S, NOT IsEmpty(S.Current)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me a slightly strange:

```
MEMBER [Dim shop.Shop id].[Shop count] AS
    Count([Dim shop.Shop id].Members, EXCLUDEEMPTY)
```

It looks like a measure so why not add it to the `[Measures]` hierarchy?

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Shop count] AS
    Count([Dim shop.Shop id].Members, EXCLUDEEMPTY)
```

You might need to add some context to the measure:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Shop count] AS
    Count(
      nonempty(
        [Dim shop.Shop id].Members
       ,{[~ROWS_Dim country].currentmember, [~ROWS_Dim shop].currentmember}) 
      )
    )
```

I'm unsure what standard `mdx` mondrian will use but also the following  would be better with the keyword `existing`:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Shop count] AS
    Count(
      nonempty(
        EXISTING [Dim shop.Shop id].Members
       ,{[~ROWS_Dim country].currentmember, [~ROWS_Dim shop].currentmember}) 
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try Hierarchize ( [DimShops].[Shop Id].members)